# Restructure array data and fill in empty value based on the existing data

Tags: php, arrays

**Data**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 1
            [total] => 0
            [numrow] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 16
            [total] => 0
            [numrow] =>        //should fill in 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 5
            [total] => 3
            [numrow] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 6
            [total] => 5
            [numrow] =>     //should fill in 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 92
            [total] => 15
            [numrow] => 2
        )
)
```

Sorry for asking stupid questions. Currently, I have stuck in this logic, I want to fill in the empty data value inside the array, it will loop all the data and get the current **numrow** data and then +1 and fill into the empty value. Any expert can help with this ya?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Sounds like you need to get the `max()` value of the `numrow` column and the `foreach()` over the array and fill in the empty values.

Comment: Hi, perhaps loop over the array by reference `https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php`

Comment: @NigelRen ya this is what I need to do, but I still stuck in this part.

Comment: Not sure how you want to work out the `current numrow`

Comment: @RiggsFolly needs to get the current max number of 'numrow' and then fill into the empty value inside the array accordingly.

Comment: In a random fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following logic might help you on your way - the source array is called `$arr`. You can get the max for column `numrow` using `max(array_column())`:

```
$max = max(array_column($arr, 'numrow'));
foreach($arr as $key0 => &$value0) {
    foreach($value0 as $key1 => &$value1) {
        if($key1 === 'numrow' && $value1 === '') {
            $value1 = ++$max;
        }
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/6eZBS)

Comment: Finally, work. Thanks a lot .....

Comment: glad I could help!